# Why isn't my variable from another class method being registered?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My variable in my parameter method is not being called in another class.

I tried telling it that we are getting the PlayerdmgAmount from the playerlivesdisplayed class. I get an error that says that PlayerLivesDisplay can not be converted to an int.

So I comment that out and wrote in the int value again. The code runs, but it is not doing what I want it to do.

```
public class PlayerLivesDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void takeLives(int PlayerdmgAmount)
    {
        playerLives -= PlayerdmgAmount;
        displayUpdate();

        if (playerLives <= 0)
        {
            //TODO load mainMenu
        }
    }

}//playerLives

public class DamgePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D othercollision)
    {
        //PlayerLivesDisplay PlayerdmgAmount = GetComponent<PlayerLivesDisplay>()

        int PlayerdmgAmount = 1;
        FindObjectOfType<PlayerLivesDisplay>().takeLives(PlayerdmgAmount);
    }
}

public class Attacker : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0f, 10f)] [SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 1f;
    [SerializeField] int PlayerdmgAmount = 1;
    GameObject currentTarget;

    public void hurtplayer(int PlayerdmgAmount)
    {
        FindObjectOfType<PlayerLivesDisplay>().takeLives(PlayerdmgAmount);

    }

}
```

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Have the attacker script have Player dmg amount on them.

Golem1 = take 5 lives away

Fox: takes 2 lives away

2. Pass these variables (when collided) to the players health damage (DamagePlayer script)
3. Then go to the player lives display class takeLives method and input the damage variables into the parameters that was initiated from the attackers script.

Answer (score 1):

If your `takeLives` method takes an `int` variable as argument, you cannot pass your `PlayerLivesDisplay` object, you need to pass an `int` instead (that's what the error is about). `PlayerLivesDisplay` may contain the `PlayerdmgAmount` (so the `int`) but is not in itself the `PlayerdmgAmount`.
Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could do something like:

In your `PlayerLivesDisplay` add a property and use it to store the value that you need to get later on:

```
public class PlayerLivesDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    public int PlayerdmgAmount { get; set; }
    ...
    public void takeLives(int playerdmgAmount)
    {
        ...
        this.PlayerdmgAmount = playerdmgAmount;
    }

}
```

Now you can access the value in other classes:

```
public class DamgePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D othercollision)
    {
        int playerdmgAmount = GetComponent<PlayerLivesDisplay>().PlayerdmgAmount;
        ...
    }
}
```